# Plugin Error in QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I have created a new plugin in QGIS3 with PyQt5 using Plugins Builder and when i want to add my code in module.py gives an error

the code used is

```
    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer_list = []
    for layer in layers:
            layer_list.append(layer.name())

    self.dlg.comboBox.addItems(layer_list)
```

the error message is

> AttributeError: 'QgisInterface' object has no attribute
>   'legendInterface'  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/REDADRISSI/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\reda\module.py",
>   line 187, in run
>       layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers() AttributeError: 'QgisInterface' object has no attribute 'legendInterface'

Comment: Hello Kadir, thanks for your reaction, i tried this solution and gives another error   NameError: name 'QgsProject' is not defined

Comment: Adding `from qgis.core import QgsProject` will probably fix your problem.